# Error while using java.exe

Tags: java, windows, command, command-prompt

I have created a class file **HelloWorld.class** which is in "C:\myData" using javac.exe.

At command prompt I am at **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin>** since I have my java.exe here.

When I execute **java C:\myData\HelloWorld** it gives me the following error :

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin>   java  C:\myData\HelloWorld**

**Error: Could not find or load main class C:\myData\HelloWorld**

Can some one please assist.

How should I specify the path of my HelloWorld.class file to java.exe. (I wish to resolve this without setting classpath or any environment variables).

Below is my HelloWorld.java code :

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

Regards.

Comment: Update question with your HelloWorld class code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it the other way around, go to the directory where you have `HelloWorld.class` and do

```
cd C:\myData\HelloWorld
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" HelloWorld
```

Comment: Not working ...C:\myData>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe HelloWorld
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Updated, you need to enclose the java path in double quotes, like this: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" HelloWorld`

Comment: Thanks..thanks...thanks...krzyk.... :) ...got the output ...feeling like a coder :) :) ...just one little thing ...why do we need quotes...

Comment: It's windows thing, if there is a space in the directory, command prompt assumes you are adding parameters to the command, so to ease implementation they came up with the double quotes

Comment: Thank you very much for taking out time and replying.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double-check the contents in HelloWorld.java. Do you have a public static void main method?

Comment: yes .. i have ..public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}